# CSS not recognized when served with FastAPI

Tags: python, http-status-code-404, fastapi

I have a FastAPI app built and an index, css and js file that work when opened directly, but I can't get the css file to show up when being served with FastAPI. I've tried troubleshooting in case the problem is a CORS issue, I've tried re-arranging the files so as to be in the same or different directories (and re-specifying the href path accordingly) but nothing has worked. This is my directory at this point:

```
working_directory
└── app
|__ index.html
    ├── style.css
    └── main.js
```

With the app home route set up like so:

```
file_path = "index.html"

@app.get("/")
async def home():
    return FileResponse(file_path)
```

Would I need to also provide the path to the css file within the file_path variable? The formats I've tried haven't worked thus far and errors with FastAPI aren't as well documented as with Flask or Django, for example.

My error looks like this:
*GET http://localhost:8000/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)*

How would I get the web app to recognize my style.css file?

Answer (score 21):

You need to actually serve the static files. Below's an example doing so with FastAPI. In a 'real world' scenario you would probably leave serving these files to a reverse proxy, like nginx.

Consider the following structure;

```
src
  app/main.py
  static/css/main.css
  templates/index.html
```

main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from pathlib import Path


app = FastAPI()

app.mount(
    "/static",
    StaticFiles(directory=Path(__file__).parent.parent.absolute() / "static"),
    name="static",
)

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")


@app.get("/")
async def root(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse(
        "index.html", {"request": request}
    )
```

index.html

```
...
<link href="{{ url_for('static', path='/css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
...
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! This is very helpful!:)